# URL with multiple optional parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Suppose I have page for searching cars, page takes 3 optional parameters, `brand`, `year` and `color`

Simplified route example:

```
Route::get('/cars/{brand?}/{year?}/{color?}', function ($brand = NULL, $year = NULL, $color = NULL) {

    echo "brand is:".$brand."<br>";
    echo "year is:".$year."<br>";
    echo "color is:".$color."<br>";

});
```

I don't realise how to pass  for example only `year` parameter?

Works if passed all of 3 parameters, for example: `/cars/_/2010/_` but this is very inelegant solution.

What is proper way for this ?

Comment: Can you give some examples of URLs that you would like to work?

Comment: @Jonathon - I expected Laravel had something like "named parameter routing way", for example `/cars/year:2010`, but parameters are depending on order, so I have no idea, how to build  URL, when I need to pass only certain parameters

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is possible since you may end up passing only 2 parameters and Laravel wouldn't be able to understand if this is `brand`, `color` or `year`.

I will leave my two cents regarding on my method of URL parameters that I use:

```
public function getCars(Request $request){
        Validator::validate($request->all(), [
            'brand' => 'nullable|string',
            'year' => 'nullable|integer',
            'color' => 'nullable|string'
        ]);

        $cars = Car::select('id', '...');

        if($request->has('brand')){
            // get cars with that brand
            $cars->where('brand', $request->brand);
        }

        // ... and so on with the other parameters

        $cars = $cars->paginate(10); // or $cars->get()

    }
```

This is a fairly simple example so you will have to customize to your needs. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As the official documentation says, *Route parameters are injected into route callbacks / controllers based on their order*. In this specific case, the only way Laravel has to know which is each parameter is like you suggest (see https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-parameters).

Anyway, if 3 parameters are required to perform a search, you could probably think of changing the request verb from **GET** to **POST**, and pass all of them as POST request data instead of in the query string itself.